# Role doesn't appear in database, but `getRoles` should always add ROLE_USER

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I tried to store a user in the database.

When I create a new user, the role doesn't appear in database, even if my function inside my "candidate" entity says that any user should have at least the role `USER_ROLE`

```
public function getRoles(): array
{
       $roles = $this->roles;
       // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
       $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

       return array_unique($roles);
}
```

[image: Here is what I'm talking about]

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The getter method is not called when **storing** data in the DB.

First the object is retrieved from the DB and its properties populated. `getRoles()` read from those properties (specifically from `$this->roles`, which should reflect the DB content.

What `getRoles()` does is make sure that even if you didn't assign any role to a specific user (as the case for your second row), the **application** will see that the user has the `USER_ROLE` assigned.

Comment: thanks sir i understand better. I need to understand how to persist and flush now to make it appear in DB

Comment: you just pass an array of "roles" to `setRoles($roles)`, then persist and flush.